# Column in table cannot be referenced when executing SQL query: column does not exist

Tags: sql, python-3.x, postgresql

When trying to insert test data in my DB with the code below I get this error. I know my database is set up correctly and works with my Flask application, but I cannot seed the database with values from my `MOCK_DATA.csv` file

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn) column "content" does not exist
LINE 3:         (content, rating, book_id, (SELECT user_id FROM user...
                 ^
HINT:  There is a column named "content" in table "reviews", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.

[SQL: --sql
        INSERT INTO reviews VALUES
        (content, rating, book_id, (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username=%(username)s))
        --endsql]
[parameters: {'username': 'Brent'}]
```

**Schema: reviews table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS reviews (
    review_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    content TEXT,
    rating INTEGER,
    user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users,
    book_id INTEGER REFERENCES books
```

**Schema: users table**

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    username VARCHAR(255),
    password VARCHAR(255)
```

**seed.py**

```py
FILE = open("MOCK_DATA.csv")
reader = csv.reader(FILE)

firstline = True
for username, password, content, rating in reader:
    # skip first line of csv file
    if firstline:
        firstline = False
        continue

    # fill users table
    DB.execute(
        """--sql
    INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES 
    (:username, :password) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
    --endsql""", {
            "username": username,
            "password": generate_password_hash(password)
        })

    print("added user")

    # add review for user
    DB.execute(
        """--sql
    INSERT INTO reviews VALUES
    (content, rating, book_id, 
    (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username=:username))
    --endsql""", {
            "content": content,
            "rating": rating,
            "book_id": 288,
            "username": username,
        })

    print("added review")
    DB.commit()
```

**MOCK_DATA.csv**

```
username,password,content,rating
Brent,OoDQgc,"Sed vel enim sit amet nunc viverra dapibus. Nulla suscipit ligula in lacus. Curabitur at ipsum ac tellus semper interdum. Mauris ullamcorper purus sit amet nulla. Quisque arcu libero, rutrum ac, lobortis vel, dapibus at, diam.",1
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference in VALUES clause the column names of the target table.

Try instead in SQL something like:

```
INSERT INTO reviews (content, rating, book_id) VALUES
    (v_content, v_rating, v_book_id,
    (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username=:username))
```

where the v_xxx variables are defined in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running a single query in DBeaver and figured out that I was interpolating the values wrong, so VALUES should be (:content, :rating, :book_id, etc)

Also usernames aren't unique, therefore I had to add `LIMIT 1` to the `SELECT` statement for `username`

```py
FILE = open("MOCK_DATA.csv")
reader = csv.reader(FILE)

firstline = True
for username, password, content, rating in reader:
    # skip first line of csv file
    if firstline:
        firstline = False
        continue

    # fill users table
    DB.execute(
        """--sql
    INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES 
    (:username, :password) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
    --endsql""", {
            "username": username,
            "password": generate_password_hash(password)
        })

    print("added user")

    # add review for user
    DB.execute(
        """--sql
    INSERT INTO reviews (content, rating, book_id, user_id) VALUES
    (:content, :rating, :book_id, 
    (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username=:username LIMIT 1))
    --endsql""",
        {
            "content": content,
            "rating": rating,
            # add book_id for book you want to add the reviews for
            "book_id": 288,
            "username": username
        })

    print("added review")
    DB.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error in my case. My query was like :

```
insert into myTable
   select
   (SELECT COALESCE (Max(idTable) + 1, 1) ),
   999,
   'foo'
```

Was fixed by adding 'from table', i.e:

```
insert into myTable
   select
   (SELECT COALESCE (Max(idTable) + 1, 1) from myTable),
   999,
   'foo'
```